# How can I share a library between Docker containers?

Tags: c++, qt, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker and I would like to create my first app using two containers with Docker compose.

My first container contains the Qt library and the second container contains the OpenFace library.

I want to use the Qt container to build (with qmake) my C++ project that refers to the OpenFace library in the second container.

So, I created a docker-compose.yml file like this:

```
version: "3"

services:
 openface:
  image: algebr/openface:latest
  tty: true
  devices:
   - "/dev/video0:/dev/video0"
  environment:
   - DISPLAY=$DISPLAY
  volumes:
   - "$HOME/.Xauthority:/root/.Xauthority:rw"
   - "./Workspace:/Workspace"

 qt:
  image: sgclark/trusty-qt59
  volumes:
   - "./Workspace:/Workspace"
```

The Workspace folder is the shared folder that contains the C++ project.

The containers start correctly but I don't have the result that I expected.
When I build the project with qmake it returns error because it can't find the OpenFace library.

Am I using Docker in the right way? If yes, how can I fix my set up to build and run the app?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: How are you building your project? Post the build scripts or commands if possible.

Comment: Sure, I'm using the command `qmake ./Workspace/HeadPose/HeadPose.pro -spec linux-g++`. The command qmake is found but it can't find the OpenFace library. I don't know exactly how to refer to the libary in the other container in my .pro file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers are isolated from each other so they cannot see each other processes or filesystems. In your example the workspace directory will be available to both containers but each container can only access their own filesystem and the workspace directory.

To be able to access both Qt and openface at the same time you will have to "merge" both docker images in one. Merge in this case means to write a Dockerfile where you use sgclark/trusty-qt59 as a base then install the openface libraries so both will be available to build your software.

Docker doesn't provide a way to merge two images so you'll end writting a 3rd image using one of these two as a base.

Comment: Thank you, I created a container with Qt and OpenFace and it works